# How can visualize the terms of a sequence in a discrete space where the discrete metric applies?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Could somebody provide some simple examples of a sequence in a discrete metric space? Thank you.

Comment: $a_n=n \in\mathbb{N}$ with discrete topology.

Comment: Here's what's special about sequences in a discrete space: let $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ be sequence in a discrete space. Then $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}x_n=L$ iff there is a $N$ such that $x_n=L$ for all $n\ge N$.

Comment: Thank you. How does one understand distance for a sequence in a discrete topology. If we have a sequence with just 5 terms, how does one understand the concept of 1 unit of distance? It has to be 1 unit of distance from any one term to every other term.